# Javascript requestAnimationFrame - HowTo stop program running and wait until drawn?

Tags: javascript, canvas, requestanimationframe

I wrote a small program in javascript where a person is basically moving over a field hunting mushrooms, after every move (N,E,S,W) i want to redraw the whole canvas and i also want to see it on my browser in the HTML canvas object. I tried to use `requestAnimationFrame` but i only see the canvas at the end of the program, while the program is running the browser is jut white, but i want to refresh the picture everytime the person moves, i tried it like this:

```
function Guy(startPosition) {
    this.position = startPosition;
}
Guy.prototype.moveTo = function (direction) {
    if (direction == "N") this.position.x -= 1
    else if (direction == "S") this.position.x += 1
    else if (direction == "W") this.position.y -= 1
    else if (direction == "E") this.position.y += 1
    checkIfMushroom(this.position);
    requestAnimationFrame(drawField);
}
```

And then i have this function, in which the player moves to the mushroom (changing its x and y coordinates):

```
function walktToMushroom(pos) {
    while (!player.position.equals(pos)) {
        var dx = player.position.x - pos.x;
        var dy = player.position.y - pos.y;
        while (dx != 0) {
            if (dx < 0) player.moveTo("S");
            else player.moveTo("N");
            dx = player.position.x - pos.x;
        }
        while (dy != 0) {
            if (dy < 0) player.moveTo("E");
            else player.moveTo("W");
            dy = player.position.y - pos.y;
        }
    }
}
```

`drawField` just redraws everything (mushrooms, player, field) with `ctx.stroke()`.

How can i update the frame everytime the `player` (which is of type `Guy`) moves?

Edit: `drawField` function:

```
function drawField() {
    requestAnimationFrame(drawField);
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    drawRaster();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#2FA0FF";
    ctx.lineWidth = 3;
    ctx.rect(player.position.x * rasterSize, player.position.y * rasterSize, rasterSize, rasterSize);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
    mushrooms.forEach(function (mush) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.strokeStyle = "#A120FF";
        ctx.lineWidth = 3;
        ctx.rect(mush.x * rasterSize, mush.y * rasterSize, rasterSize, rasterSize);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.closePath();
    });
}
drawField();
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the `requestAnimationFrame` function and just directly call `drawField()`?

Comment: Yes, also doesn't work.

Comment: If i debug my application with chrome and i only use `drawField()` i can see the single steps!

Comment: Does that mean it's working for Chrome?

Comment: Its working if i debug every single `drawField`, but i only see white if i run the program.

Comment: May I ask how quickly you are calling `walktToMushroom(pos)` you might be clearing the canvas faster than it can draw thus just showing white. (also typo with your function name, the extra "t"? "walktTo..")

Comment: I am calling it in a while loop until every mushroom is consumed: `while (mushrooms.length > 0){...walkToMushroom(pos);}`

Comment: It would be good to include an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question. In particular, seeing the `drawField` function might be very helpful. A snippet would be ideal!

Comment: Oh I just see that your `moveTo` calls are within the while loop which is far too quick for the canvas to redraw. I'd recommend using a `setInterval` with 100ms to see whether that's the problem.

Comment: I added `drawField`, this doesn't change anything: `setInterval(function () {drawField();}, 100)`

Comment: Thanks. Your question sounds very related to and might be solved by [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37480609/962603).

Comment: @binaryBigInt That's not what I mean, but the link posted by Just a student is what you want.

Comment: @binaryBigInt You cannot do that in a loop if you expect it to take some time. You'll need to do it asynchronously - use a recursive approach with callbacks instead. You then can wait after each step to render a frame.

Comment: How could i rewrite my `walkToMushroom` so that the browser has time to call `drawField` inbetween? I updated my `drawField`.